# Invalid Signature in my Ionic 3 app woo-commerce-api

Tags: typescript, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I just installed `woocommerce-api`, created new api keys (api is enabled) in woocommerce and did a simple call to get products and test it in my ionic 3 application, but I'm getting this error:

> {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"Invalid signature - provided signature does not match."}]}

This is my code:

```
WooCommerce: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.WooCommerce = WC({
        url: "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php",
        consumerKey: "ck_d165ee6b1c1f85fc17f5a615a9a630f6d7fb086a",
        consumerSecret:"cs_a1c208feeb9d9aec03acfdc50cef20ae93294f7a",
    });

    this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products/categories")
        .then((data) => { console.log(data); }, 
              (err) => { console.log(err); })
}
```

any help?

Comment: Never used woocommerce before, but to me it seems like a problem with authentication (Not really an ionic or typescript issue). Perhaps it's a mismatch in API versioning, or that you didn't specify API version at all?

Comment: I have specified and tried (v3) but still am gettin this error